# Limit of a function $g_k(x)$ when the limit $g_k(y)/g_k(z)$ is known.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, limits

Let $g_k(x)$ be a decreasing function respect to $x$ defined in $\mathbb{R}$ which satisfies the condition
$$
\frac{g_k(y)}{g_k(z)} \to \infty \text{ when } k \to \infty \quad \text{and whenever } \, y<z. 
$$
Can we deduce anything about the limit $g_k(x) \to \infty$ as $k \to \infty$?

Maybe that this limit is almost always $0$ or $\infty$?

Or maybe if we add some additional conditions we can say something? I’m a bit unsure about this.

Comment: What is the purpose of $k$ in $g_{k}(x)$?

Comment: @Kplusn if $g_k(x)=\exp(-kx)$, then $g_k(0)\to 1$ as $k\to\infty$ (and $0$ or $+\infty$ for $x\neq 0$).

Comment: @ShreyJoshi What do you mean? It’s just an index that denotes that the function also depends on $k$.

Comment: @user254433 Yes, you are correct. But I’m not interested in particular examples.

Comment: Oh so $g_k(x)$ is like $g(k, x)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $x_0$ be such that $\lim_{k\to\infty}g_k(x_0) = A$ and $A$ is not $0$ nor $\infty$. Then by your condition for any other $x$ we have either $g_k(x)/g_k(x_0) \to\infty$ or $g_k(x)/g_k(x_0)\to 0$ as $k\to\infty$. But in both cases we have 
$$
\lim_{k\to\infty} \frac{g_k(x)}{g_k(x_0)} = \frac{1}{A} \lim_{k\to\infty}{g_k(x)}.
$$
We can make a conclusion now.